# VBA Macro cannot find folder path

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro (with the help of several internet sources) that will iterate through files in a SharePoint folder online and extract the needed info out of said folder, then move onto the next.

However, it does not seem to locate the folder path and produces an error telling me it cannot locate folder path. I have checked the path by copying and pasting the folder into google chrome and it works.

I'm sure this will be a silly and stupid fix but i cannot seem to get it to work.

```
Sub ExtractComments()

Dim mswb, slwb As Workbook
Dim mscommentsws, mssheetsenteredws, slcommentsws, slcoverpagews As Worksheet
Dim mscommentswslrow, mssheetsenteredwslrow, slcommentswslrow As Long
Dim folderURL As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file


folderURL = InputBox("Please enter Sharepoint link of the Internal VV folder")

If folderURL = vbnullstirng Then Exit Sub

Set fso = New FileSystemObject

If Not fso.FolderExists(folderURL) Then
    MsgBox ("Folder does not exist")
    Exit Sub
Else
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderURL)
End If

Set mswb = ThisWorkbook
Set mscommentsws = mswb.Sheets("AllComments")
Set mssheetsenteredws = mswb.Sheets("SheetsEntered")

mscommentswslrow = mscommentsws.Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
mssheetsenteredwslrow = mssheetsenteredws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each file In folder.Files

    Set slwb = Workbooks.Open(folderURL & file.Name)
    Set slcommentsws = slwb.Sheets("Comments")
    Set slcoverpagews = slwb.Sheets("Cover Page")

    Dim fileURLrange, URLname As Variant
    Dim count As Long

    slcommentswslrow = slcommentsws.Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    fileURLrange = mssheetsenteredws.Range("A1:A" & mssheetsenteredwslrow)
    URLname = f.Name
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a path your entering?

Comment: There is a typo in `If folderURL = vbnullstirng Then Exit Sub` => vbNullString

Comment: You can't expect the file system to be able to browse a sharepoint folder from the URL. You need to locate (or perhaps convert from the URL) the actual file 'path'. If you open the URL in I.E. and then view library in File explorer, you'll see the kind of path you need.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module.

Comment: `Set slwb = Workbooks.Open(folderURL & file.Name)` If you are getting an error at this line and `folderURL` has a valid path then ensure that there is "\" at the end of the path and `folderURL & file.Name` creates a valid finename/path for example `C:\myfolder\myfoler\myfile.xlsx` You can also use `DIR(folderURL & file.Name)` to check if filename and path are correct

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for the responses. I have corrected the typo thanks. @CLR, i am unsure what you mean, how do i convert the to a file path. I have used the URL before to extract data from a file which worked perfectly, how come it does not work when using the URL for a folder

Comment: Also, @SiddharthRout, adding a "\" did not make a difference

Comment: Hi Lawrence, perhaps I've assumed incorrectly. Can you give us an idea of the type of URL you're using? Maybe block out the identifying elements?

Comment: https://sp.XXXX.com/ddps/XXXX/Deliveries/00_XXXX/06_XXXX/01%20-%20Internal%20XXXX/GR6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following structure for your URL:

`\\sharepoint.yourfirmname.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\site-name\library-name\`

This would translate from the webpage URL of:

`https://sharepoint.yourfirmname.com/sites/site-name/library-name/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

leave the `@SSL\DavWWWRoot` part as it is, no need to change.

---

---

Also, ensure that you can connect to the server using **Windows** explorer.

Paste the path into **Windows** explorer. If you get an error it may be that the path is invalid, or possibly that the connection has timed out. A quick way to check/fix both is to

- Open **Internet** Explorer
- Browse your sharepoint to the library in question
- Then,

  - If using 'classic experience' view, go to the *Ribbon>Library>Open with explorer*
  - if not using 'classic' view, go to view selector menu roughly under the Share button and click *View in File Explorer*

This will force a new connection to the server and you can now copy/paste the full path from the **Windows** Explorer address bar.

The path should then work just like other windows filesystem paths. Especially if you use the `@SSL\DavWWWRoot` method above. In my experience though, it will need 'reconnecting' from time to time. Usually every few days or after a reboot.

Comment: No luck with this method. I had tried something similar before

Comment: Also, you'll need to ensure a connection is present to the folder. Make sure you can open the folder using the path you're inputting, but by pasting that exact path into **windows** Explorer.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work either. Thanks for your help though

Comment: When you say it didn't work.. do you mean you can't enter the path into windows explorer? If so, then that's what's causing your issue. The path is not valid. Possibly because you've not connected.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to cover off connecting.